# Using Google Analytics SDK for Android v3

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have used Google Analytics v2 earlier and could send app name , app version and set anbonimize Ip using the below code:

```
        m_GaTracker.setAnonymizeIp(true);
        m_GaTracker.setAppName("MyRemote");
        m_GaTracker.setAppVersion(m_appVersion);
```

where `m_GaTracker` is an instance of Google Analytics Tracker.

I am now migrating to V3 but this code does not work any more .I get this error:

```
The method setAnonymizeIp(boolean) is undefined for the type Tracker
```

How to solve this issue or is there any other way I can send these values using Google Analytics v3?

Already checked [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration) but its of no use!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe now you need to use the `set` method.

```
Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-XXXX-Y");

// Values set directly on a tracker apply to all subsequent hits.
tracker.set(Fields.ANONYMIZE_IP, true);
```

There is a field reference at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference. (It's written for analytics.js, which the v3 analytics are meant to align with.)

You can also see the list of Fields strings by decompiling the libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar:

```
public final class Fields
{
  public static final String ANONYMIZE_IP = "&aip";
  public static final String HIT_TYPE = "&t";
  public static final String SESSION_CONTROL = "&sc";
  public static final String NON_INTERACTION = "&ni";
  public static final String DESCRIPTION = "&cd";
  public static final String SCREEN_NAME = "&cd";
  public static final String LOCATION = "&dl";
  public static final String REFERRER = "&dr";
  public static final String PAGE = "&dp";
  public static final String HOSTNAME = "&dh";
  public static final String TITLE = "&dt";
  public static final String LANGUAGE = "&ul";
  public static final String ENCODING = "&de";
  public static final String SCREEN_COLORS = "&sd";
  public static final String SCREEN_RESOLUTION = "&sr";
  public static final String VIEWPORT_SIZE = "&vp";
  public static final String CLIENT_ID = "&cid";
  public static final String CAMPAIGN_NAME = "&cn";
  public static final String CAMPAIGN_SOURCE = "&cs";
  public static final String CAMPAIGN_MEDIUM = "&cm";
  public static final String CAMPAIGN_KEYWORD = "&ck";
  public static final String CAMPAIGN_CONTENT = "&cc";
  public static final String CAMPAIGN_ID = "&ci";
  public static final String EVENT_CATEGORY = "&ec";
  public static final String EVENT_ACTION = "&ea";
  public static final String EVENT_LABEL = "&el";
  public static final String EVENT_VALUE = "&ev";
  public static final String SOCIAL_NETWORK = "&sn";
  public static final String SOCIAL_ACTION = "&sa";
  public static final String SOCIAL_TARGET = "&st";
  public static final String TIMING_VAR = "&utv";
  public static final String TIMING_VALUE = "&utt";
  public static final String TIMING_CATEGORY = "&utc";
  public static final String TIMING_LABEL = "&utl";
  public static final String APP_NAME = "&an";
  public static final String APP_ID = "&aid";
  public static final String APP_INSTALLER_ID = "&aiid";
  public static final String APP_VERSION = "&av";
  public static final String EX_DESCRIPTION = "&exd";
  public static final String EX_FATAL = "&exf";
  public static final String CURRENCY_CODE = "&cu";
  public static final String TRANSACTION_ID = "&ti";
  public static final String TRANSACTION_AFFILIATION = "&ta";
  public static final String TRANSACTION_SHIPPING = "&ts";
  public static final String TRANSACTION_TAX = "&tt";
  public static final String TRANSACTION_REVENUE = "&tr";
  public static final String ITEM_SKU = "&ic";
  public static final String ITEM_NAME = "&in";
  public static final String ITEM_CATEGORY = "&iv";
  public static final String ITEM_PRICE = "&ip";
  public static final String ITEM_QUANTITY = "&iq";
  public static final String TRACKING_ID = "&tid";
  public static final String SAMPLE_RATE = "&sf";
  public static final String JAVA_ENABLED = "&je";
  public static final String FLASH_VERSION = "&fl";
  public static final String USE_SECURE = "useSecure";
  static final String API_VERSION = "&v";
  static final String CLIENT_VERSION = "&_v";
  static final String USAGE_TRACKING = "&_u";
  static final String QUEUE_TIME = "&qt";
  static final String HIT_TIME = "&ht";
  static final String CACHE_BUSTER = "&z";
  static final String GCLID = "&gclid";
  static final String DCLID = "&dclid";
  static final String GMOB_T = "&gmob_t";
  public static final String ANDROID_APP_UID = "AppUID";
```

The android documentation for analytics could be much better.